# Solve the equation$\sqrt{b^2 + 2ax} = x+a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

At an exercise I get the  following equation: 
$$\sqrt{ b^{2} + 2ax} = x+a$$

My steps would be:
$b^2 + 2ax = x^2 + a^2$
so $b^2 + 2a - a^2 = x$

But this is completely wrong!

Comment: First hint: What is $(x+a)^2?$

Comment: x^2 + 2ax + a^2.. ofcourse.
I got it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A common but serious mistake;

$$(a+b)^2 \neq a^2+b^2, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$